# are there options to speed up dpkg-buildpackage

Tags: build, ffmpeg, debian, deb, dpkg

Im back porting ffmpeg to an older version of debian.
everything is going well, but its so slow. 
I am running `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`

with a debian rules file that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_configure:
    ./configure
```

I notice, this is only processing on 1 core. 
is there anything like make -j 4 that I could use to speed this up?

I've been using this guide, but i don't see anything for speeding up the build step
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use `-j 4` as an argument to dpkg-buildpackage. It is documented in the man page. The relevant section is:

> -jjobs Number of jobs allowed to be run simultaneously, equivalent to 
>   the make(1) option of the same name. Will add itself to 
>   the  MAKEFLAGS environment  variable,  which  should  cause  all 
>   subsequent  make  invocations to inherit the option. Also adds
>   parallel=jobs to the DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS environment variable which
>   allows debian/rules files to use this information for their  own 
>   purposes.   The  parallel=jobs in DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS environment
>   variable will override the -j value if this option is given.

Comment: Or with newer dpkg-buildpackage versions the `-J` option which might be safer in case the build-system does not support parallel building.

Comment: I didn't get any of the mentioned options to work, then I added `--parallel` to `dh $@`